# Group by - Distinct Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to get my table to display like this using pivot tables dynamically

```
month           |   Hugo | Marco |
january 2017    |   5    |       |
february 2017   |   3    |       |
january 2017    |        |  4    |
february 2017   |        |  7    |
```

How could I group the month-year to display like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
month           |   Hugo | Marco |
january 2017    |   5    |  4    |
february 2017   |   3    |  7    |

SET @query ='SELECT * FROM(SELECT
          petstoreemployee.employeefirstname as employeefirstname
          ,sum(petID.breed) as breeds
          ,Format(date, ''MMMM-yyyy'') as Month

   FROM
          petID, petstoreemployee
   WHERE
          petID.petstoreemployeeID=petstoreemployee.petstoreemployeeID and
          petID.ProjectedPrjID=1
          and
          (petID.date >= ''2017-01-01 00:00:00:000'' AND petID.date <= 
  ''2017-12-31 00:00:00:000'')
   group by petstoreemployee.employeefirstname, Format(date,''yyyy'')

)
as d
PIVOT(
   avg(breeds)
   for employeefirstname
   IN (' + @pet + ')
) as p'

exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: add a GROUP BY month and use SUM for the columns Hugo & Marco

Comment: select MONTH,max([Hugo]) [Hugo] ,max([Marco]) [Marco] FROM #Table11
group by MONTH

Comment: I did do group by month? **Format(date,''yyyy'')**  @EstebanP.

Comment: How would I get #table11? @Chanukya

Comment: CREATE TABLE #Table11
    ([month] varchar(13), [Hugo] INT, [Marco] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO #Table11
    ([month], [Hugo], [Marco])
VALUES
    ('january 2017', 5, NULL),
    ('february 2017', 3, NULL),
    ('january 2017', NULL, 4),
    ('february 2017', NULL, 7)
;
select MONTH,max([Hugo]) [Hugo] ,max([Marco]) [Marco] FROM #Table11
group by MONTH

select *
from 
(
  select *
  from #Table11
) src
pivot
(
  MAX([Hugo])
  for [month] in ([january 2017], [february 2017])
) piv;.....@vanillacoke9191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try put the select "source" into a nested select subquery before grouping. something like this.

```
          SET @query ='SELECT [month],' + @pet + ' FROM(

                    SELECT t.employeefirstname,
                           SUM(t.breed) AS breeds,
                           t.[Month]
                    FROM (
                             SELECT     petstoreemployee.employeefirstname AS employeefirstname ,
                                        petID.breed,
                                        FORMAT(date, ''MMMM-yyyy'') AS Month
                              FROM      petID 
                                        JOIN  petstoreemployee ON
                                        petID.petstoreemployeeID = petstoreemployee.petstoreemployeeID
                              WHERE     petID.ProjectedPrjID = 1
                                        AND ( petID.date >= ''2017-01-01 00:00:00:000''
                                              AND petID.date <= ''2017-12-31 00:00:00:000''
                                            )

                            )T
                             GROUP BY  t.employeefirstname,t.[Month]
            )
            as d
            PIVOT(
               avg(breeds)
               for employeefirstname
               IN (' + @pet + ')
            ) as p'

            exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: It's giving me an incorrect syntax error near ',' ... I can't seem to spot it :(

Comment: @vanillacoke9191  hmm it seems it's in the joining part...  based on your script. I assume PetID is a table, I updated the script. Hope it works.